# ¿Cómo ver todos los datos que devuelve el value_counts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de ver todos los datos que devuelve la función `value_counts` de Pandas, ya que pareciera que cuando el conteo tiene varias filas, solo muestra una especie de resumen y yo necesito ver la totalidad de los datos. Lo tengo definido de esta forma:

```
cerosdf = pd.DataFrame((ceros), columns = ['Device Name','Time','Value'])
freq_ceros = cerosdf['Device Name'].value_counts()

def conteo():
    print('Cantidad de ceros reportados por medidor:\n')
    print(freq_ceros)
    print('\n')
```

Y el output al llamar a la función definida como `conteo()` es el siguiente:

```
Cantidad de ceros reportados por medidor:

air16102377    371
air14443588    138
air16149053     63
air13269817     31
air17032512     24
              ... 
air14567489      1
air16943195      1
air12411540      1
air17080413      1
air14999754      1
Name: Device Name, Length: 94, dtype: int64
```

En teoría hay 94 filas pero únicamente me muestra 10. ¿Hay algún modo de ver todas?

Comment: En que entorno (Editor o IDE) estás ejecutando tu código python y puedes poner un ejemplo del contenido de tu dataframe.

Comment: Usa `pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)` al inicio de tu script.